# Lua Regex to capture whole line

Tags: regex, lua

Can you help me? I'm trying to capture a entire line using Regex (LUA script)
Here is some lines that appear on my console (note that it is a game server, by the way)

```
JOIN FAILURE: Player (192.168.1.74:49352) can't join (failed to load map: map or tileset is damaged/wrong)<br>
JOIN FAILURE: XaxXakTXaxX (111.111.111.111:12574) can't join (failed to load map: map or tileset is damaged/wrong)<br>
JOIN FAILURE: gm 'pLa (222.222.222.222:65807) can't join (failed to load map: map or tileset is damaged/wrong)<br>
JOIN FAILURE: ~ * Mark (198.15.177.24:22144) can't join (failed to load map: map or tileset is damaged/wrong)
```

Note that after **JOIN FAILURE:, it appear player nickname + (user ip:port) + fixed message error**

How can I create a regex to match whole line? I just have this regex to capture IP addr => `(%d+)%.(%d+)%.(%d+)%.(%d+)%:(%d+)`

I have no idea about how to create a regex to match all symbols to capture player nickname.

Thank you.

Comment: Is not much important to capture player nickname, just `(IP:PORT) + can't join (failed to load map: map or tileset is damaged/wrong)`

Comment: you mean something like: `nickname, ip, port, message = line:match('JOIN FAILURE: (.-) %(([%d.]+):(%d+)%) ([^\r\n]+)` ? `(.-)` means as little as possible before user ip

Comment: With this regex, it is only capturing player nickname

Comment: https://rextester.com/ZJW38799

Comment: Also, is important to specify on regex the line "can't join (failed to load map: map or tileset is damaged/wrong)", otherwise, it will match another errors following this pattern.

Comment: See https://rextester.com/WTE19853

Comment: You did'n mention in question that you need the special message. Then it must be like: `local nickname, ip, port = line:match('JOIN FAILURE: (.-) %(([%d.]+):(%d+)%) can't join %(failed to load map: map or tileset is damaged/wrong%)`. It returns 3 groups: *nickname*, *ip* and *port* in the same pattern

Comment: Thank you all and sorry disturbing!